# Switching type recursion on and off

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I'm working on a simple compiler. It starts off with a complicated data structure which is recursive (i.e., it's an expression tree), and ends up with exactly the same data structure, but with recursion disallowed.

"No problem", I thought to myself, "I'll just make the recursion type a type parameter, and then define type synonyms for the recursive and non-recursive types".

...ah, yes, but it turns out you can't actually do that. You see, type synonyms are not allowed to be recursive. >facepalm<

Any idea how I can achieve what I'm after?

---

Here's a very simplified example. Suppose I have these two data types:

```
data Type1 = Foo ID | Bar [Type1] | Baz Type1 Type1

data Type2 = Foo ID | Bar [ID] | Baz ID ID
```

My plan was to simply do this:

```
data Type r = Foo ID | Bar [r] | Baz r r

type Type1 = Type Type1
type Type2 = Type ID
```

But obviously that doesn't actually work.

Currently, it appears my options are these:

1. Ignore the problem, and don't try to enforce this restriction in a type system.
2. Duplicate the entire type definition (including renaming all the constructors).

Neither of these is really satisfactory. For the trivial example above, duplicating the type isn't too bad; for a *big* type definition, you do not want to be doing this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
data Type r = Foo ID | Bar [r] | Baz r r

newtype Type1 = Type1 (Type Type1)
newtype Type2 = Type2 (Type ID) -- or type Type2 = Type ID, but this is more consistent
```

You need to remove an extra type constructor in functions dealing with `Type1`, but this shouldn't be a major problem.

More generally, you can define [a fixed-point type constructor](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.ru/2010/12/type-level-fix-and-generic-folds.html) and use it for defining `Type1`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid hundreds of wrapping and unwrapping operations, but it seems there's no other way. :-S

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: I would use pattern synonyms to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

This sound like you might use [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes). You basically have two options:

- Use [`Fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#t:Fix) (or `Mu` or `Nu`) for creating the recursive variant, which means some nuisance with (un)wrapping its constructor all the time.

  ```
  data TypeF r = FooF ID | BarF [r] | BazF r r
    deriving (Functor)

  type Type1 = Fix TypeF
  type Type2 = TypeF ID
  ```
- Define your own variant for the recursive case and implement `project`/`embed` as needed:

  ```
  data Type = Foo ID | Bar [Type] | Baz Type Type

  type instance Base Type = TypeF

  instance Foldable Type where
      project (Foo ID) = FooF ID
      project (Bar xs) = BarF xs
      project (Baz x y) = BazF x y

  instance Unfoldable Type where
      embed (FooF ID) = Foo ID
      embed (BarF xs) = Bar xs
      embed (BazF x y) = Baz x y
  ```

  The type family `Base` provides the connection between the two: `project` and `embed` witness the isomorphism between `Type` and `Base Type Type`, and `Base Type Type` is equivalent to `TypeF Type`, unwrapping one level of recursion.

In both cases `Foldable` and `Unfoldable` implement various *-morphisms for converting between the recursive and non-recursive representations.